# Obtaining an authenticode for an Azure application

Tags: azure, code-signing, whois, authenticode

I am in the process of trying to obtain an authenticode certificate for our online application. I have paid for the cert (through KSoftware a reseller of Comodo). They insist that they require the WHOIS information of the sites address to match the company name/address etc.

Here's the problem, the application is hosted in Azure. When I query the WHOIS record for our sites address it returns Microsoft details!

Perhaps someone has been through the process of getting an Azure application signed or knows of any good references I can take a look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a service and deploy your application to Windows Azure it runs with  DNS name i.e. yourservicename.cloudapp.net.

However if you have a domain name i.e. yourdomainname.com then you sure can set your domain as primary place for your users to come (or any request to come) and then all the requets will be redirected to Windows Azure site (*.cloudapp.net). To make it happen you need to setup CNAME setting in your DNS registrar to send all requests from your domain to Windows Azure application. @Smarx has explained the process [here to follow](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure).

Now when you use Authenticode certificate your  authenticated request must be handled by your original domain, yourdommainname.com not with your servicename.cloudapp.net. When you have CNAME set for your site yourdomainname.com you will get correct WHOIS info as return by your domainname.com registrar which will be validated correctly by Authenticode certificate.

Comment: Hey Avkash, I was wondering if it is possible to have the authenticode set up without rerouting all requests? i.e. - have an authenticode on the myservicename.cloudapp.net? Thanks again!

Comment: As far as I know the authenticode certificate is validated directly from domain for which the certificate is issue and you will not get certificate issued for *.cloudapp.net so, It may not work. Please double check with CA for much finer details..